# PDFBOX security not working

Tags: security, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX - 1.8.13, it seems that PDF Security is not working as expected. If owner password is set and user password is not, PDFBOX allows to decrypt my PDF File if I don't provide owner password . Please help where I am doing WRONG.

The code for encrypting my pdf file :

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/home/dummy/dummy.pdf"),null);

AccessPermission perms = new AccessPermission();
perms.setCanAssembleDocument(false);;
perms.setCanExtractContent(false);
perms.setCanModify(false);
perms.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
perms.setCanExtractForAccessibility(false);
perms.setCanFillInForm(false);

perms.setCanPrint(false);
perms.setReadOnly();
perms.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
perms.setCanExtractForAccessibility(false);

document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(false);

StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("AdminPasswordTest", "", perms);
policy.setPermissions(perms);

document.protect(policy);

document.save("/home/dummy/dummy_secured.pdf"); 

document.close();
```

The code for decrypting my PDF

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("/home/dummy/dummy_secured.pdf", true);

if (doc.isEncrypted()) { //remove the security before adding protections
    doc.decrypt(""); //This should not be DECRYPTED because owner password is not provided
    doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true); //This user is not provided this permissions
}
doc.save("/home/dummy/dummy_decrypted.pdf");
doc.close();
```

Comment: See also this: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt

Answer (score 5):

> it seems that PDF Security is not working as expected.

In that case you need to adjust your expectations. ;)

This is effectively how PDF password encryption works:

- The **user password** is the password actually used for encryption and decryption.
- The **owner password** allows to access (a pre-processed version of) the user password in the PDF which then can be used to decrypt the document.

The empty user password "" you used for encryption, therefore, is all the password anyone needs to decrypt the PDF.

Using the owner password instead of the user password also allows you to decrypt the PDF (see above, it allows the PDF processor to retrieve the user password to then continue and decrypt the file) and additionally tells the PDF processor that you are owner of the document and, therefore, shall not be restricted by any of the permissions not given in the document at hand.

PDF libraries usually either don't care about the permissions at all (AFAIK PDFBox doesn't) or have a switch to override restrictions due to a missing owner password (e.g. iText).

Thus, encrypting a PDF using an empty user password (to restrict permissions while letting anyone open the file) is an obstacle which is really easy to overcome.

Comment: if I use doc.decrypt("<USER PASSWORD>"); then eventhough document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(false); for user, all security can be removed by document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true); the PDFBOX does not validates w.r.t. Owner password. It seems a bug in PDFBOX. Please clarify

Comment: As I wrote in my answer "PDF libraries usually either don't care about the permissions at all..."; you could call that a *missing feature*. I doubt, though, that there is much interest in that feature by PDFBox users, so it will hardly be given any priority... and consider what happened with iText: there is a mechanism in it requiring the owner password for certain operations, and what happened at first? People patched that mechanism out of it and many unofficial iText versions started floating around. IText then introduced an override switch, users merely have to set a global variable...

Comment: It essentially makes no sense to implement restrictions based on soft permissions (like here in PDFs) in open source libraries.

Comment: BTW... *then eventhough document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(false); for user* - this is **not a permission setting** which can be seen already from the fact that it is a `document` setting, not a `perms` setting.

Comment: Please lemme know the steps how to secure my PDF using pdfbox-1.8.13

Comment: What security are you actually looking for?